# Database Connections Timing Out (Connection Pooling On Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, connection, pooling

My dB connections are constantly timing out. I looked through some of the solutions people have offered to this, and have implemented them, but nothing has worked out till now. Any new thoughts, will be very helpful.

**Problem**
For some requests to the webapp, this is the error I am getting :

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully
>   received from the server was 11,198,881 milliseconds ago. The last
>   packet sent successfully to the server was 11,198,881 milliseconds
>   ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You
>   should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity
>   before use in your application, increasing the server configured
>   values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection
>   property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

**Solutions Tried**

1. Testing connection validity
2. Using autoReconnect

**Contents of context.xml**

> Resource name="jdbc/dBConnectionMain" auth="Container"
>   type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" maxIdle="18"
>   removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
>   validationQuery="select 1" testOnBorrow="true" username="user"
>   password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true" /

Any pointers on this?

Cheers,
RD

Comment: Any logs available from the MySQL server? Under which cirumstances does the problem occur (immediately or after a certain amout of uptime)?