# Tomcat-Mysql connections in a Connection Pool timing out after idle time

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am currently using tomcat 6 and MySQL 5.1.56.
It uses Mysql Connector-j to get DB connections and use them. 
I have setup a connection pool as per this link.

http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html

Everything works fine as long as I am using it.

If I leave it idle for a few hours then I am not able to execute any queries.
I get the following exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: **No operations allowed after connection closed.**
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: **Communications link failure**

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31,858,914 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 11 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
```

I saw another person on stack overflow the same question but with not answer.
[Database Connections Timing Out (Connection Pooling On Tomcat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095687/database-connections-timing-out-connection-pooling-on-tomcat)

I found a solution here but I cannot use it as it directs me to use another third party application which I do not have permission to do so.

```
https://groups.google.com/group/ctjug-forum/browse_thread/thread/c326d3595d0c91af
```

Is there any way I can solve this problem without having to resort to deploying third party jars/apps.

I have already tried the options such as autoreconnect, test connection before and after connection was accessed and all other options.

This is my current setup in conext.xml

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/appdb"  auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="**********" 
              password="**********" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb?autoReconnect=true"
              maxActive="15"  maxIdle="3"
                testWhileIdle="true"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="false"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              validationInterval="30000"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"/>
```

What is the best practice solution in this case?

I couldn't find anything in the mysql logs.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not leave any connection open for hours.

You should have a persistence layer that gets a connection from a pool, performs the operation(s), commits or rolls back, and closes the connection to return it back to the pool in the smallest scope possible.  Your application will be far more scalable if you don't limit yourself to one connection per session.  Your app will be responsive enough, because the pool will amortize the cost of opening each connection over all your requests.

Some pools have configuration that allows you to check a connection before letting it out of the pool and provide a fresh one if it's stale.  See how to do it with your pool/app server.

Comment: yes thats what i am doing. The problem occurs after the connections are returned back to the pool. If I leave the application unused for a few hours, then the connections from within the pool becomes unusable. That is the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: @kensenjohn: How did you solve the issue? I use the same configuration except for autoreconnect. It works, but if I use SSL I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Add following attributes to your resource tag

```
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
validationInterval="YOUR_VALIDATON_INTERVAL"
```

and tomcat will validate the connection when borrowing it from connection pool.

Comment: You will notice in my question that I had set all those parameters but I am still having issues. I wrote the question after exhausting all those options.

Answer (score 1):

I have this configuration working for a while but I connect to an Oracle database. I feel 30 seconds is too short for the validationInterval and timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis but it only means that the tests will run more frequently.

Apart from that, I have set numTestsPerEvictionRun to  "-1" which means that it will test *all* the idle connections. Now, the document clearly states that this property is not in use, so really cannot tell whether it will help. You will have to try it to find out.

```
numTestsPerEvictionRun="-1"
```

Comment: I will try this out,  but as you mentioned, it does specify that tomcat does not use this parameter. Thank you.